# add new column to dataframe with if, else statement

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, data-manipulation

I would like to add a new column (class) to my data frame (counties) by using an if-else statement.

**dataframe**:
[image: dataframe]

here's my code

```
#set working directory
  setwd("C:/Users/weirc/OneDrive/Desktop/Undergrad Courses/Fall 2021 Classes/GHY 3814/final project/data")
  
  #load packages
  library(readr)
  library(dplyr)
  
  #load data
  counties <- read_csv("vaxData_counties.csv")
  
  calc <- if (counties$Series_Complete >= 75) {
    print(4)
  } else if (counties$Series_Complete >= 50) {
    print(3)
  } else if (counties$Series_Complete >= 25) {
    print(2)
  }else print(1)
  
  #create new column for class
  counties %>% mutate(class=calc)
```

here's a screenshot of the error I receive in the console:

[image: screenshot]

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your data, but in your `if-else if-else` statement, conditions like `counties$Series_Complete >= 75` are now comparing whole vector with single value, and if using `print`, it may not give you proper result. Instead, try using `dplyr::case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
counties %>%
  mutate(class = case_when(
    Series_Complete >=75 ~ 4,
    Series_Complete >= 50 ~ 3,
    Series_Complete >= 25 ~ 2,
    TRUE ~ 1
  ))
```

Comment: worked beautifully, preciate you! @Park

Answer (score 1):

I like @Park's answer. If you didn't want to use `dplyr` though, you could use `ifelse`. You can chain `ifelse` to mimic the behavior of `case when` statements: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse

```
counties$class <- ifelse(counties$Series_Complete >= 75, 4, 
ifelse(counties$Series_Complete >= 50, 3, 
ifelse(counties$Series_Complete >= 25, 2, 1)))
```